# Add/Enable handler mapping in IIS 7/7.5 using WIX 3.5

Tags: c#, iis, installation, wix, wix3.5

WIX 3.5 works using IIS6 for adding wildcard but for IIS7/7.5 there are 2 problems.

1. Handler Mappings is disabled by default

   - Have to navigate to "Edit Feature Permissions" and check "Scripts" to allow.
2. Wildcard mapping is not added using the IISWixExtension library.

   - I need to do this manually for IIS7/7.5

The user will have no idea how to do the above. Yes, very non-technical people.

Cheers

Comment: Any idea I need work this out?

Comment: you can do this by using custom action. call custom action which will use C# code to do the settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by updating the web.config file with the appropriate tags that the UI will recognise. EASY!!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you did?

Answer (score 0):

Here is example using Wix 3.5. I use this for install PHP on IIS:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>

      <Custom Action="CreateFastCGI" Before="InstallFinalize">
          <![CDATA[NOT Installed AND VersionNT64 >= 600]]>
      </Custom>
      <Custom Action="AddHandlerMappingsIIS2" Before="InstallFinalize">
          <![CDATA[NOT Installed AND VersionNT64 >= 600]]>
      </Custom>

  </InstallExecuteSequence>

  <CustomAction Id="CreateFastCGI" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" Return="ignore" Directory="TARGETDIR"
                ExeCommand="[SystemFolder]inetsrv\appcmd set config /section:system.webServer/fastCGI /+[\[]fullPath=&#39;[ApplicationPhpDirectory]php-cgi.exe&#39;[\]]" />
  <CustomAction Id="AddHandlerMappingsIIS2" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" Return="check" Directory="TARGETDIR"
                ExeCommand="[SystemFolder]inetsrv\appcmd set config /section:system.webServer/handlers /+[\[]name=&#39;PHP_via_FastCGI&#39;,path=&#39;*.php&#39;,verb=&#39;*&#39;,modules=&#39;FastCgiModule&#39;,scriptProcessor=&#39;[ApplicationPhpDirectory]php-cgi.exe&#39;,resourceType=&#39;Unspecified&#39;[\]]" />
```

Comment: The right person will work means please don't be hard on yourself for anxiety. This is a hard time for so many. Side note you are helping a trend with this being the time with the most breakups according to fb